# How to get a list of objects contained only specific fields in Java?

Tags: java, json, list, arraylist

I have a list of object from type Person:

```
String id
String name
String address
String workPlace
```

I want to create a new list contain Person objects but only with 2 fields: id and name.
I want to create a json from that list later that looks like this:

```
[
{
"id": "767384",
"name": "Bob",
},
{
"id": "202330",
"name": "Alice",
}
]
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: create a JSON arraylist, and then inside a loop, create new json object and put id and name of person inside the json object and in the end insert the json object into the json array list.

Answer (score 0):

The library is com.google.gson.JsonArray and org.json.JSONObject

First thing to do is create a JSON Array.

```
JsonArray jsonPersonList = new JsonArray();
```

Then create a loop (assuming there is a list known as personList ).

```
for(Person person : personList)
```

Then create a new json object inside the loop.

```
JsonObject personJson = new JsonObject();
```

put the person attributes inside the json object.

```
personJson.addProperty("id" , person.getId()); //Assuming getters,setters
personJson.addProperty("name" , person.getName());
```

In the end of the loop, add the personJson to JsonPersonList.

```
jsonPersonList.add(personJson);
```

After the loop you would have a json list with your desired persons.

Example method:

```
public JsonArray getPersonJsonList(ArrayList<Person> personList){
   JsonArray jsonPersonList = new JsonArray();
   for(Person person : personList){
      JsonObject personJson = new JsonObject();
      personJson.addProperty("id" , person.getId());
      personJson.addProperty("name" , person.getName());
      jsonPersonList.add(personJson);
   }
return jsonPersonList;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < personList.size() ; i++)` - really? This is a **really bad** recommendation - if you don't know why, look it up. `for(Person person : personList)`. Then getting from the `List` twice as well makes it worse. OP says "_list_" - what makes you think `ArrayList`? Program to the `interface`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know about the for each loop, editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a new result Object or DTO, like that

```
public class ResultPerson {

    String id;
    String name;

    public ResultPerson(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and then you can map your Person list to your new list by using java stream and convert it to json by making use of ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<ResultPerson> results = persons.stream().map(person -> new ResultPerson(person.getId(), person.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
try {
    String json = ow.writeValueAsString(results);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You'd need to add **jackson-databind** as dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

if you don't use maven you can download the jar and add it to your classpath